infinite loop occur when i reading text file and comparing it in c
i currently having problem finding out why the program currently looping infinite(i think so)
when i run it, it will run infinitely and won't stop or print the next part
the first three function is for some context but all of them work perfectly fine
int calNoRec(int choice, int num, FILE** station, FILE** time) {
    double display = 0;
    int recTotal = 0, recNum;
    chooseFileRead(choice, &station, &time);
    while (fscanf(time, "%lf|", &display) != EOF)
        recTotal++;
    fclose(station);
    fclose(time);
    recNum = ceil(recTotal / num * 1.00);
    return recNum;
}
int calStation(int choice, FILE** station, FILE** time) {
    char stations[100];
    int noStation = 0;
    chooseFileRead(choice, &station, &time);
    while (fscanf(station, "%[^\n]\n", stations) != EOF)
        noStation++;
    fclose(station);
    fclose(time);
    return noStation;
}

This is the part where it loop inifinitely
void searchFromToWithTime() {
    FILE* time, * station;
    int stationNum, recordNum;// how many times to loop
    int choice = 0;// which line and direction
    int enter = 0;// enter for press enter to continue
    stationName s[100];
    double display[100][100];
    TicketAvailiableDetails ticket[1000], buy[100];
    char departureStations[30], destinationStations[30];
    double departureTimes;
    int i, j, h, fileNo, departNum = -1, destiNum = -1, ticketNo, ticketWanted, buying = 0;
    char repeat;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the departure station  : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", &departureStations);
        rewind(stdin);
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            departureStations[i] = toupper(departureStations[i]);
        printf("Enter the departure time     : ");
        scanf("%lf", &departureTimes);
        rewind(stdin);
        printf("Enter the destination station: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", &destinationStations);
        ticketNo = 0;
        rewind(stdin);
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            destinationStations[i] = toupper(destinationStations[i]);
        for (fileNo = 1; fileNo < 15; fileNo++)
        {
            stationNum = calStation(fileNo, &station, &time);
            recordNum = calNoRec(fileNo, stationNum, &station, &time);
            chooseFileRead(fileNo, &station, &time);
            for (j = 0; j < recordNum; j++)
                for (h = 0; h < stationNum; h++)
                    fscanf(time, "%lf|", &display[j][h]);
            for (i = 0; i < stationNum; i++)
            {
                fscanf(station, "%[^\n]\n", s[i].name);
                if (strcmp(departureStations, s[i].name) == 0)
                    departNum = i;
                if (strcmp(destinationStations, s[i].name) == 0)
                    destiNum = i;
                if (departNum != -1 && destiNum != -1)
                    if (departNum < destiNum)
                    {
                        for (j = 0; j < recordNum; j++)
                        {
                            if (display[departNum][j] > departureTimes)
                            {
                                strcpy(ticket[ticketNo].departureStation, departureStations);
                                strcpy(ticket[ticketNo].destinationStation, destinationStations);
                                ticket[ticketNo].departureTime = display[departNum][j];
                                ticket[ticketNo].destinationTime = display[destiNum][j];
                                ticketNo++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
            departNum = -1, destiNum = -1;
            fclose(station);
            fclose(time);
        }
        if (ticketNo == 0)
            printf("No Ticket Found!\n");
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < ticketNo; i++)
                printf("%d. %s --> %s  |  %.2lf - %.2lf\n", i + 1, ticket[i].departureStation, ticket[i].destinationStation, ticket[i].departureTime, ticket[i].destinationTime);
            do
            {
                printf("Enter the ticket number wanted (-1 to exit): ");
                scanf("%d", &ticketWanted);
                rewind(stdin);
                if (ticketWanted == -1)
                    exit(-1);
                buy[buying] = ticket[ticketWanted-1];
                printf("Buy another one(Y/N) :");
                scanf("%c", &repeat);
                repeat = toupper(repeat);
                buying++;
            } while (repeat == 'Y');
        }
        printf("Find another ticket? (Y/N)");
        scanf("%c", &repeat);
        repeat = toupper(repeat);
        system("cls");
        fclose(time);
        fclose(station);
    } while (repeat != 'Y');
}

find out why is it not working

rewind(stdin); ==> Um, what is this supposed to do? Were you perchance trying to discard any excess input?

scanf("%c", &repeat); ==> This requires a space before c.

while (fscanf(time, "%lf|", &display) != EOF) ==> compare against 1 here.

Most scanf formats skip leading white-space, like the newline left in the input buffer from previous input. But not %c or %[]. For them to work like the others you need to add a leading single space first in the format string.
